# How to send .docx attachment using Python

Tags: python-3.x, mime

I've successfully e-mailed and verified **.txt/.ppt/.pdf** files but using the same code I'm unable to open the attachment from the e-mails from this script.

```
filename = "textfile.docx"
part = MIMEBase('application', "octet-stream")
part.set_payload(open("textfile.docx", encoding = "ISO-8859-1").read())
encoders.encode_base64(part)
part.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename=filename)
msg.attach(part)
```

Answer (score 0):

DOCX is a zipped format so it is a binary file. Hence your code is using a western ISO plain text encoding to read the file: `open("textfile.docx", encoding = "ISO-8859-1")` is simply wrong. You could read the binary stream by open it as a byte stream instread of encoded plain text. Then encode it to base64 directly from bytecode. not using any text encoding. Which would in many other cases be wrong anyways. Somebody might send utf-8 encoded plaintext instead of western ISO encoded might also cause artefacts with your current script.