# Sending mail with (docx)attachment using python

Tags: python, email, docx, mime

I have been trying to send a mail via python with a Docx attachment

I'm able to get a mail but with no attachment to it, below is the code I used for attaching a file
And I didn't get any error while attaching a file

```
import smtplib, ssl
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email import encoders

sender_email = email
receiver_email = toemail
password = password

message = MIMEMultipart("alternative")
message["Subject"] = Subject
message["From"] = sender_email
message["To"] = receiver_email
message.attach(htmlmessage)

attach_file = open(attach_file_name, 'rb') # Open the file as binary mode
payload = MIMEBase('application', 'octet-stream')
payload.set_payload((attach_file).read())
encoders.encode_base64(payload)
#encode the attachment
#add payload header with filename
payload.add_header('Content-Disposition', "attachment; filename= %s" % attach_file)
message.attach(payload)

context = ssl.create_default_context()
with smtplib.SMTP_SSL("smtp.gmail.com", 465, context=context) as server:
    server.login(sender_email, password)
    server.sendmail(
        sender_email, receiver_email, message.as_string()
    )
```

Comment: We need a [mre] to be able to reproduce...

Comment: This is minimum reproducible example

Answer (score 1):

Mime types are to be respected. The type multipart/alternative should be used for messages containing the same information in plain text and in HTML. The mail reader can then choose which representation it can use.

On the other hand, multipart/mixed should be used when the message contains multiple *different* parts, said differently to transport *attachements*.

So, provided `htmlmessage` is a valid `email.mime.text.MIMEText`, your code should not declare `"alternative"`:

```
...
message = MIMEMultipart()
...
```

Furthermore, you should avoid to directly use `MIMEBase` and instead rely on the defaults for `MIMEApplication`:

```
payload = MIMEApplication(attach_file.read(),
                'vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document')
payload.add_header('Content-Disposition',
                   "attachment; filename= %s" % attach_file)
message.attach(payload)
```

But I must acknowledge that this last point is mainly a matter of taste...

Comment: Thanks for the first part, that really solved the attachment problem. but docx file I attach seems shown as a corrupted file. I tried using your MIMEApplication instead of MIMEBase but still, the file getting attached is corrupted. Even if I use MIMEBase the attachment is still the same corrupted  <br/> There are some docx python help that says Docx is compressed binary format from [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60613396/how-to-send-docx-attachment-using-python)

Comment: @oneclick My bad. I did not pay attention enough to the type of the file and used the default for `MIMEApplication` because your code originaly used an application/octet-stream mime type. According to [this other SO post], type for a docx file shall be `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document`. I have edited my post with the correct subtype.